# "IBM Notes - View Property - ODBC Access - Generate unique keys in index" losing setting

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

```
 Sub Click(Source As Button)
  Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
  Dim uiview As NotesUIView
  Dim view As NotesView
  Dim formula As String
  formula = "SELECT (@Modified [" & (Date - 7) & "])"
  Set uiview = ws.CurrentView
  Set view = uiview.View
  view.SelectionFormula = formula
End Sub
```

Example code above. After the agent has run, the view property "ODBC Access" loses it's value and is unset.

Is there a property to set it via Lotusscript ? If not I will have to add more code to create a unique array.

Comment: Why do you permanently modify the view selection formula? What do you need this view for? Is it just programmatic access? Then use `NotesDatabase.Search( "(@Modified [" & (Date - 7) & "])" ) and don't change the view at all...

Comment: I need to create a monthly report, the formula in the example is just for reference. I am just looking for a way to set the view property.  If that's not possible I will rewrite the code, use a notesviewentrycollection, array and then arrayunique to get the unique values from a view column.